# Why Netbeans complains about "incorrect credentials" with Git?

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am trying to use Git with Netbeans.
My command for cloning is

```
git clone git+ssh://git@git.renater.fr:2222/simol.git
```

with no passphrase. I have tried many different configurations but I don't managed to clone my repository. For example, for the repository url I choose:

> git+ssh://git.renater.fr:2222/simol.git

with 'git' as username and no passphrase. I get the following error message:

> Incorrect credentials for repository at git+ssh://git.renater.fr:2222/simol.git

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprinsigly, it worked after rerunning Netbeans. I read this solution of some forums but I thought it was not possible. Especially, the syntax git+ssh is of course correct and understood by Netbeans.

Answer (score 4):

The format for the URL is not git+ssh it is either `ssh://user@server/project.git` or `user@server:project.git` as described in [Git - The Protocols (The SSH Protocol) of The Pro Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol)

Try :

```
git@git.renater.fr:2222:simol.git
```

Other possible problems include:

- you haven't generated your SSH public key,
- didn't not set it up on your server,
- you are using a kind of public key not supported by the server or disabled on the client (~/.ssh/config ) Some of the older public key types are disabled by default on newer SSH servers or clients.